# WebService implementation in ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, web-services, adobe, flash-cs4

How can I call WebService using ActionScript 3. from my initial findings, I come to know it is AS3 dosen't support WebService and SOAP, it was in Flash MX/AS2 though.

Any suggestions or links guys??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use the Flex framework, Carlo Alducente wrote a nice [WebService](http://alducente.wordpress.com/2007/10/27/web-service-in-as3-release-10/) class, as3 only(no mx.rpc.* dependencies ). I've tried it and it works just fine.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

What about the [WebService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/langref/mx/rpc/soap/WebService.html) class?
Otherwise I think WebServices are just xml, so it could not be that hard to implement something by you own.

Comment: Thanks for reply Hippo but as George mentioned, I dont want flex dependency so, I can't use this class. :(